# Translate SQL query into codeigniter for joomla

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model, joomla

I have written a SQL query which works fine and output provides all the data that I need:

Please see this screenshot:

[image: QUERY result]

This is the SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    P.name, C.project_id, C.choice_id, C.time_stamp, P.id, 
    P.description, T.type, P.activated
FROM
    (SELECT P.*
     FROM aqoru_pt_project P
     JOIN
         (SELECT id, MAX(creation_date) AS latestUpdate
          FROM aqoru_pt_project
          GROUP BY id) t ON t.id = P.id AND t.latestUpdate = P.creation_date) P
JOIN
    (SELECT C.*
     FROM aqoru_pt_project_choice C
     JOIN
         (SELECT project_id, MAX(time_stamp) AS latestDate
          FROM aqoru_pt_project_choice
          GROUP BY project_id) t ON t.project_id = C.project_id AND t.latestDate = C.time_stamp) C ON P.id = C.project_id
LEFT JOIN 
    aqoru_community_groups_members CGM ON P.group_id = CGM.groupid
INNER JOIN
    aqoru_pt_project_type T ON P.type_id = T.id
WHERE
    P.user_id = 569 OR CGM.memberid = 569
    AND CGM.permissions = 1
    AND P.deactivated != 1
GROUP BY 
    P.id
ORDER BY 
    P.id;
```

Now I need to push it into php format I was trying without great success as I am struggling mainly with the part where I try to put Join in select on the very beginning of the code. Definitely the part after `ON P.id = C.project_id` works fine. The problem occurs when I try to add max value from other table.

This is the code I wrote, but it does not work:

```
public function getProjects($userID)
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $columns = array('P.id', 'P.name', 'P.description', 'T.type', 'P.activated');
        $query
            ->select(array('P.id', 'P.name', 'P.description', 'T.type', 'P.activated', 'max(C.time_stamp) as max'))
            ->from($db->quoteName(
                ->SELECT ('P.*')
                ->FROM ($db->quoteName('aqoru_pt_project', 'P')
                ->JOIN($db->quoteName(
                    ->SELECT ('id', 'MAX(creation_date) AS latestUpdate')
                    ->FROM ($db->quoteName('aqoru_pt_project')
                    ->group($db->quoteName('id')) 't' .  ' ON t.id = P.id AND t.latestUpdate = P.creation_date') P
                ->JOIN(
                  ->SELECT ('C.*')
                  ->FROM ($db->quoteName('aqoru_pt_project_choice', 'C')
                    ->JOIN($db->quoteName(
                    ->SELECT ('project_id', 'MAX(time_stamp) AS latestDate')
                    ->FROM ($db->quoteName('aqoru_pt_project_choice'))
                    ->group($db->quoteName('id')) 't' .  ' ON t.project_id = P.project_id AND t.latestUpdate = P.time_stamp') 'C' . 'ON P.id = C.project_id'

            ))
            ->leftjoin($db->quoteName('#__community_groups_members', 'CGM') . ' ON P.group_id = CGM.groupid')
            ->innerjoin($db->quoteName('#__pt_project_type', 'T') . ' ON P.type_id = T.id')
            ->where(
                $db->quoteName('P.user_id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($userID),
            )
            ->orwhere(array(
                $db->quoteName('CGM.memberid') . ' = ' . $db->quote($userID),
                $db->quoteName('CGM.permissions') . ' = 1'
            ))
            ->andwhere($db->quoteName('P.deactivated') . ' != 1')
            ->group($db->quoteName('P.id'))
            ->order('P.id DESC');
        /*
         * Note: for some reason the queries return duplicates on the production site not on my local site
         * So we must group by projectID to avoid duplicates. I am not aware what is causing this duplication
         */

        return $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();
    }
```

Comment: If you can dump the SQL queries generated by the getProjects(), you can compare it with your classic sql query. 
I'm not familiar with Joomla but in Codeigniter you can do it using `$this->db->last_query()`

Comment: Joomla has its own query building methods so I recommend using that instead of CI's active record (as a matter of consistency between code core and custom code).  Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange to gain the attention of professionals who have an intimate understanding of the CMS and its extensions.  If you search JSE before asking, you will find many pages that demonstrate how to `dump()` a query (several of which were posted by me).  I think you need to declare a subquery in advance.  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352+%24subquery

Comment: Thanks guys. I am appologise for not serching before posting.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->select('P.name,C.project_id,C.choice_id,C.time_stamp,P.id,P.description,T.type,P.activated')
->from('(SELECT P.*
     FROM aqoru_pt_project P
     JOIN
         (SELECT id, MAX(creation_date) AS latestUpdate
          FROM aqoru_pt_project
          GROUP BY id) t ON t.id = P.id AND t.latestUpdate = P.creation_date) P')
->join('(SELECT C.*
     FROM aqoru_pt_project_choice C
     JOIN
         (SELECT project_id, MAX(time_stamp) AS latestDate
          FROM aqoru_pt_project_choice
          GROUP BY project_id) t ON t.project_id = C.project_id AND t.latestDate = C.time_stamp) C', 'P.id = C.project_id')
->join('aqoru_community_groups_members CGM', 'P.group_id = CGM.groupid', 'LEFT')
->join('aqoru_pt_project_type T', 'P.type_id = T.id')
->where('P.user_id', 569)
->or_where('CGM.memberid', 569)
->where('CGM.permissions', 1)
->where('P.deactivated !=', 1)
->group_by('P.id')
->order_by('P.id ASC')
->get();
```